# force ruby gem to use alternative gem source

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a gem that I one of the owner/authors (`hyperloop`) that depends on another gem (`opal-rails`) which depends on another gem (`opal-jquery`).

All gems depend on the gem `opal`.  The problem is the current released version of `opal-query` is locked to an older version of the `opal` gem.

The version of `opal-jquery` on master is okay.  For whatever reason the author(s) have not pushed ruby gems, so I have to work around this.

The work around is that I have to say

```
gem 'hyperloop'
gem "opal-jquery", git: "https://github.com/opal/opal-jquery.git", branch: "master"
```

in the application Gemfile.

I am hoping somebody can give a workaround that could be embedded in the `hyperloop` gemspec, so that the problem is taken care of there.

I thought if I added

```
gem "opal-jquery", git: "https://github.com/opal/opal-jquery.git", branch: "master"
```

to the `hyperloop` Gemfile this would take care of it, but apparently not.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't really a way to manage the dependencies of your dependencies. You have 2 options here:

1) Use an older version of opal 
2) Clone the opal-jquery gem and modify its Gemfile, pointing to the version of opal you want it to use, then, in your Gemfile, point the opal-jquery gem to pull from your cloned version of the repo

Neither of these is really ideal and you'd have issues if you ever decided to upgrade to a newer version of opal-jquery if you go with the second route

Comment: thanks.  I am one of the authors of `hyperloop` so I thought if I added an explicit reference to the opal-jquery version (on github) that works, I would be all set, but it has no effect.

Comment: sorry, used the wrong gem name, i meant to clone opal-jquery and modify its gemfile. I'll edit the answer

Comment: this version opal-jquery `gem "opal-jquery", git: "https://github.com/opal/opal-jquery.git", branch: "master"` works.   The problem is I have to explicitly specify it the application Gemfile... I am looking for a way to "hide" this inside of the `hyperloop` gem.  I.e. by adding it to hyperloop/Gemfile  but I can't get that to work.

Comment: [this blog post](https://blog.presidentbeef.com/blog/2016/08/09/bundling-gem-dependencies-inside-ruby-gems/) details a process for bundling a gem with its dependencies.

Comment: @eiko thanks.  It looks like that method only works if you include ALL the gems... I tried applying the method to just pull in opal-jquery and it doesn't work by itself..